# Does minimal submanifolds minimize area locally?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces, calibrated-geometry

Consider $(\tilde{M},g)$ a riemannian manifold and $M \subset \tilde{M}$ riemannian submanifold.

Is it true that if $M$ is a minimal submanifold of $\tilde{M}$ then for every $p \in M$ there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $p$ in $\tilde{M}$ such that $V=W\cap M$ has least area among every $\Omega \subset W$ with $\partial \Omega = \partial V$?

I've been thinking about it, I think it is true but I don't know how to prove.

If it's true, how should I go about proving it?

Comment: What's your definition for a minimal submanifold?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval we say it's minimal if the mean curvature vanishes identically, or equivalently, $M$ is a critical point of the area functional.

Answer (score 2):

The question was [re-asked in Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277009/do-minimal-submanifolds-minimize-area-locally) and get a good answer. The answer is yes and the proof uses a calibration argument. Reader who are interested only in $\mathbb R^3$ may see the following [less technical answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304967/when-is-a-minimal-surface-a-graph-and-not-area-minimizing).

Comment: In the case of $\Bbb R^3$, the calibration argument is given explicitly as an exercise in my Multivariable Mathematics book. See Exercise 22, p. 392. It's a direct application of Stokes's Theorem, just as Robert indicates in his general answer.