# Minimal surface and local minimizer of area functional

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a 3-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $\Sigma\subset M$ a closed surface. Is it equivalent to say:

1) $\Sigma$ is minimal, i.e. its mean curvature identically vanishes;

2) $\Sigma$ is a local minimizer for the area functional?

Does a characterization for minimal surface exists?

Comment: As far as I recall, the gradient of the area functional (up to a constant multiplicative scalar depending on conventions) is the mean curvature vector. So... yes?

Comment: I've heard something like that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, found one reference. See Theorem 4 in page 19 of Henri Anciaux' *Minimal Submanifolds in Pseudo-Riemannian Geometry*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a minimal graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is not area-minimizing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304967/is-there-a-minimal-graph-in-mathbbr3-which-is-not-area-minimizing)

Comment: Also see this related post on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277009/do-minimal-submanifolds-minimize-area-locally)

Comment: Then a surface is minimal iff has zero mean curvature. Thank you all.

Comment: "a surface is minimal iff has zero mean curvature" This is THE definition of a minimal surface. @GiulioBinosi

Comment: A minimal surface is a critical point of the area functional, not necessarily a local minimum.